# Cannot use firestore driven data in my flutter code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code, the basic structure of it is that it has a login/register page, a page for the user to enter their information, and a homepage. I made a bool variable that I send to the firestore which shows true if the user provided all their information and gives false otherwise. When I log in I want my code to check if the user provided all of their info. If the user did they get directed to Homepage, otherwise, they go back to the page where they are supposed to provide their information. However, my code keeps giving me an issue and indicates a value being null. I would appreciate any help.

This is how I try to choose which page to go

```
return choosePage()? Homepage():Scaffold()`
```

this is the function I use to return me the boolean value

```
choosePage() async{
    databaseReference.collection("Users").document("$userId").get().then((value){
       setState(() {
          director = value.data['All Info'];// value.data['All Info'] is the boolean that indicates whether all information are provided or not
        });
        print(director);
    });
    return director;
}
```

I get the userId used above which is also the name of my firestore document using the function below which is run as soon as the widget build starts

```
getUserId() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await widget.auth.GetCurrentUser();
    setState(() {
        userId = user.uid;
    }); 
    return user.uid;
}
```

I would also like to mention I passed a false value to my firestore field 'All Info' when I sign up and I update the 'All Info' value to true once the user presses submit and posts all their information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see you returning a `Future`, you have to return one if you are going to be using `async`, so try  `Future<bool> function() ` https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: when you **my code keeps giving me an issue and indicates a value being null**, which value are you talking about? Also, what is the `print(director)` is showing?